# How does programming FPGAs and CPLDs differ?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, verilog, programming, programmable-logic

I am learning to program programmable devices using a XC9572XL CPLD. I would like to know how much knowledge from programming CPLDs (in Verilog, VHDL) will be transferable to programming FPGAs (not necessarily Xilinx FPGAs).

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that you program a CPLD once, and it stores its configuration in non-volatile memory, and then if you power cycle it it will return to the previous configuration without needing to be programmed again. With FPGAs (except for a few special devices or families) every time you power up the device you need to re-program it.

Because of that, many FPGAs have hard-coded logic to re-program themselves from an EEPROM or flash chip after power-up.

Another thing to keep in mind is FPGAs are generally more complex than CPLDs so their configuration files are generally larger, sometimes much, much larger.

Also, the XC95 series is quite old at this point, and the configuration options available for FPGAs have evolved since then. So read the datasheet (or configuration users guide) for your FPGA to find out all the configuration options available for it and pick the best one for how you're using the device.

Comment: The initialization difference is one of SRAM-based FPGAs vs. basically everything else including other sorts of FPGAs, and so somewhat tangential to the question.  The points about the architecture and scope of the logic fabric are what really matter.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, AFAIK SRAM based FPGAs are  the vast majority of FPGAs sold. If you're designing a real system, it makes a big difference whether you are going to program your device once at production time, or need to arrange for it to be re-programmed in the field every time you turn it on.

Comment: That really depends on what you are buying a device *for*.  Also there are modern SRAM FPGA's with a configuration ROM in-package.

Comment: The OP's use of the term "programming" refers to the engineering/language skills required to produce the functional design, not the nuts-and-bolts associated with configuring the actual device.

Comment: @DaveTweed, I don't see how you can be sure of that from the text of the question. Possibly it's ambiguous, but I don't think your interpretation is certain.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, That's exactly why I said "except for a few special devices and families".

Comment: As Dave explains you really misunderstood the point of the question, with the result that only a fraction of your answer is applicable.  But the question itself is far too broad to survive, so it's probably a moot issue.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I answered the question as written. If you have a crystal ball able to read the mind of OP, you should be working the tables in Vegas, or selling financial products, not trolling StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

All of it. Think of a CPLD as a subset of what's available on an FPGA. The way you synthesize HDL to a CPLD is the same. The main difference is an FPGA typically contains IP blocks that you can include without having to write the code yourself.

There are certainly differences in the way the devices implement your logic, and the steps needed to download that implementation, but the skills need to write synthesizable RTL are the same.

Comment: Another half right/half wrong answer.  Even absent add-ons like block memories, multipliers, clock modules, etc, FPGAs and CPLDs traditionally have fundamental differences in the architecture and scope of their logic fabric and routing.  Of course there are oddball devices that have fallen in between the norms, too.  Also "IP blocks" includes libraries compiled into a design even more than it refers to fixed hardware engines on the chip.

Comment: While those differences don't typically impact the basic mechanism which a new user would use for design, they very much do impact the *scope* of the projects which can be attempted and which sort of device should be chosen for a given type of goal - CPLD's aren't all that useful for beginners.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, true, there are difference in design domain whether you are building a toaster controller, or a beam-forming satellite transponder. And the skills you need to learn about what devices are part of the platform you intend to implement your design are the same--it's just there are a different spread of IP devices.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, there are products being sold as CPLDs now that have more features and more resources than FPGAs did 20 years ago. I don't see how you can write them off as "not all that useful for beginners".

Comment: @ThePhoton - you really need to actually *read* the question.  The asker's experience with a CPLD is with the XC9572XL

Comment: 1. If you think a better answer can be written, then nothing's stopping you from writing it. 2. The fact OP is starting with XC9572 doesn't mean that "CPLD's aren't all that useful for beginners". You could redirect them to a modern CPLD just as easily as redirect them to FPGAs.